# How to set up a keyboard shortcut to open Terminal on macOS FOR FREE?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, terminal.app

Tried looking all over the internet, they all require buying third party programs that support the feature, or suggest programs that don't work for me. Like Automator.

Automator doesn't recognize Terminal.app at all if I try to set a shortcut to it, it's greyed out. So that isn't an option.

Downloading iTerm2 also isn't an option, because I did download it, and with all due respect to people who use it, it kinda sucked. I just didn't like it at all, I much prefer the default Terminal.

So.. as the title says, is there a FREE method to set up a keyboard shortcut to open Terminal on macOS? That doesn't involve any paid 3 party software, Automator or iTerm 2.

*free* 3rd party software is fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this in Automator, set as a Service [Quick Action in Mojave], inside an Applescript.

```
tell "system events" to activate application "Terminal"
```

Give the Service a key command in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.

Done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but my only issue with it is that it doesn't prompt the Terminal window to me and I have to navigate to it manually. But it did the job.

Comment: You could add an 'activate' command on the next line after the shell script [untested], but will add to answer...

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work with either ``me`` or ``current application``. Thanks for the help either way! My main goal was to kinda have it automated like the Terminal shortcut on Ubuntu.. a simple Ctrl+Alt+T (or Cmd+Alt+T on macOS) to launch the terminal for immediate use.. But I guess this isn't possible.

Comment: I presumed you'd already tried it the easy way, but I've redone it in as basic mode as possible.

Comment: Wow.. this is perfect! Thank you so much! I'd upvote your answer but I can't do so with less than 15 rep points :p

Comment: You should be able to 'accept' it using the checkmark to the left, & I gave you the first 5 on your way...

Comment: This solution looks a bit better: https://dev.to/chanyayun/set-up-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-terminal-in-mac-47f5

Comment: @GeorgePligoropoulos - then post it as an answer [giving full credit to the original] rather than burying it down here where no-one will ever see it.